# Atribuir valor a uma variável dicionário que é opcional

Tags: python, dicionário

Tenho uma função em que um dos parâmetros é um dicionário, mas é opcional.

Preciso atribuir uma valor nesse dicionário, mas ter em conta o caso em que esse parâmetro não é preenchido.

A seguinte solução usa duas linhas para isso:

```py
def uma_funcao(um_dict=None):
    um_dict = um_dict or {}
    um_dict['uma_chave'] = True
```

Acredito existir uma forma mais *pitónica* de o fazer, numa só linha. É possível?

Answer (score 14):

Não, acredito que essa forma que você apresentou já é mínima. Não posso falar sobre Python 3, pois não tenho experiência.

(Respostas na negativa são complicadas, mas não tenho nenhuma evidência que lhe dê suporte, exceto a ausência de evidência em contrário...)

---

**Atualização:** como 3 pessoas já postaram a mesma resposta incorreta, vou apontá-la aqui para evitar futuras respostas idênticas.

```
>>> def uma_funcao(um_dict={}):
...   um_dict['uma_chave'] = True
...   return um_dict
...
>>> x = uma_funcao()
>>> x['teste'] = True
>>> y = uma_funcao()
>>> y
{'uma_chave': True, 'teste': True}
```

Como podem ver, não se deve usar um [valor mutável como parâmetro padrão](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) de uma função. A expressão `{}` cria um objeto **antes** de ser usada como parâmetro, de modo que toda chamada de `uma_funcao` sem passar parâmetros usará **o mesmo** `dict`. Como raramente esse é o comportamento desejado, não há opção senão o uso de `None` seguido de um teste, tal como no código original da pergunta.

Outra forma que me ocorreu, muito comum em linguagens como C, foi unir a atribuição com o uso numa só expressão:

```
(um_dict = um_dict or {})['uma_chave'] = True
```

Entretanto isso não é permitido pela sintaxe do Python (2 ao menos; se algo assim foi acrescentado em versões futuras, não é de meu conhecimento).

Answer (score 2):

Isso aqui não serve?

```
def uma_funcao(um_dict = {}):
  um_dict['uma_chave'] = True
  return um_dict
```

Não entendo porque atribuir `None` ao invés de atribuir `{}` diretamente. Se existe alguma razão para isso, por favor entre em mais detalhes.

Comment: A razão é que **o mesmo** `dict` será usado em toda invocação de `uma_funcao` [sem argumentos], mas o comportamento esperado (intuitivo até) seria que um dict novo fosse criado a cada invocação.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de contornar o problema apresentado pelo @mgibsonbr é retornar uma cópia do dicionário ao invés dele:

```
def uma_funcao(um_dict={}):
    um_dict['uma_chave'] = True
    return um_dict.copy()
```

Note que, caso `um_dict` seja passado, ele continuará sendo modificado:

```
>>> def uma_funcao(um_dict={}):
...   um_dict['uma_chave'] = True
...   return um_dict.copy()
...
>>> x = uma_funcao()
>>> x['teste'] = True
>>> y = uma_funcao()
>>> y
{'uma_chave': True}
>>> d = {'uma_chave': False}
>>> z = uma_funcao(d)
>>> z
{'uma_chave': True}
>>> d
{'uma_chave': True}
```

É possível, ainda, fazer tudo em uma única linha, muito embora esteja longe de ser considerado algo pitônico:

```
def uma_funcao(um_dict={}):
    return um_dict.update({'uma_chave': True}) or um_dict.copy()
```